# how can use Firebase Functions to upload a .txt file from a website to Firebase Storage with python?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

```
import os
import firebase_functions
from firebase_admin import storage, initialize_app, credentials
from firebase_functions import https_fn, storage_fn
from flask import request

credentials  = credentials.Certificate()
initialize_app(credentials)

@https_fn.on_request()
def upload_file_to_firebase_storage(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    url = request.args.get('https://filesamples.com/samples/document/txt/sample3.txt')
    
    storage_fn.upload_file(url)

    return https_fn.Response("File uploaded successfully!")
```

deployed successfully, but click the http trigger, got a error:
500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

if i delete the storage_fn.upload_file(url), it will successful to display the response.

Comment: Cloud Storage SDKs can only upload local data, they have no API that takes a URL. So you'll have to download the data to the local system and then upload it to Cloud Storage, possibly by streaming it. Since Cloud Functions is a fairly small part of this problem, you migh find your answer in https://www.google.com/search?q=python+cloud+storage+upload+url